# How to check whether a file is compressed in Windows 10?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way check whether a file is compressed in the file system in Windows 10?

[`fileattrib`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileattrib.html) doesn't return the `FILE_FILE_COMPRESSION` flag.

Comment: Can't you just look at the file extension?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Compression with the file system keeps the file extension.